# Vertical align legends in highcharts with two column

Tags: legend, highcharts

I am using high charts, In that how to have legends vertically aligned legends with more columns(instead of having a navigation for legends), js 
 fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/aarthi_101/ruw8t3p9/6/

```
legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top'
      itemMarginBottom: 5
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that look of the legend with a help of a little trick. Change the type of the legend to `floating` and set `spacingRight` to create the space for the legend. Notice that it's done with the default **horizontal** `layout`. `legend.width` & `legend.itemWidth` allow you to make sure that 2 columns will be used (`width` / `itemWidth` has to be higher or equal to 2 and lower than 3). `legend.x` adjusts the position of the whole legend.

```
  chart: {
    marginRight: 200,
    (...)
  },

  legend: {
    floating: true,
    align: 'right',
    itemMarginBottom: 5,
    width: 180,
    x: 25,
    itemWidth: 90
  },
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/avo0cgnt/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/

Comment: Works fine, Thanks